# Select inputs with number type through jQuery

Tags: jquery-selectors, types, numbers, html, html-input

How can I select all inputs with number type in jQuery?

The following code doesn't work:

```
$(':input[type="number"]').click(function () { 
   alert('hello'); 
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: code example? That 'should' work as far as I can see

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your selector is correct. Using the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), it will select input elements with that type.

You'll need to be sure the DOM is loaded before running it.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/H2aQr/

```
$(function() {
    $(':input[type="number"]').click(function () { alert('hello'); });
});
```

Comment: `onclick` doesn't appear to fire when I click on the arrows

Comment: @Josh, you mean in the example? It works for me. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Also, you have to drop the colon from `:input` for IE support

Comment: @jAndy: You probably haven't seem my other comment yet, but that's not the case for `:input`.

Comment: @Josh: Strange. I'm using 9.0.597.67 beta, and it's fine. I don't understand why `:` would need to be dropped for IE. It's a valid jQuery/Sizzle selector, and just a shortcut for *input, textarea, select and button elements*. http://api.jquery.com/input-selector

Comment: @Patrick Yeah, it appears like it's a bug.  The numbers being displayed inside the box when I click the arrows are also not right.

Comment: @Josh: Still strange that you don't get the alert. If I initialize the input with a number, the buttons increment/decrement the number properly. http://jsfiddle.net/H2aQr/1/

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the colon at the beginning, that's for selecting types of input, like $('input:text')

so `$('input[type="number"]').click(function () { alert('hello'); });`

works just fine

Answer (score 2):

i think your problem is the ":" before input.

try:

```
$('input[type="number"]').click(function () { alert('hello'); });
```

Comment: That's a valid selector (with the colon). It's called the [input-selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector)

Comment: nope, the `:` is bad practice because of the implicite usage of the universal selector, but it's not the problem here.

Comment: i my firefox it only works without ":". maybe there is some problem

Comment: @jAndy: For most of those types it is, but not for this one (though it still is selecting more than needed). This is just a shortcut for selecting all form tags. Something like `:checkbox` is a shortcut for `[type='checkbox']`, which implies universal selection.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here your code works well... http://jsfiddle.net/U47Vj/ Maybe your Browser does not support this [HTML5 Feature](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.number.html). In Chrome everything is fine. Same code in FF 3.6 breaks.